# How to create userstory in rally through an api?

Tags: rally

Does rally provide any built in api to create user story?
We need an api which can create userstories in rally by ca technologies through our web application.

Answer (score 1):

What language are you looking to interact with?  There are a bunch of tools.

HTML/JS (Custom apps): https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/

Java: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava

.NET: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET

Ruby: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby

And more...

There are also tons of code examples floating around once you have a language picked out...